# How can I deploy old commits to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

We're trying to deploy a big Rails project to Heroku for the first time, but something's breaking during the Heroku compilation process and we have [**no way of knowing what**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079445/how-to-debug-error-detecting-the-assetsprecompile-task-issue-on-heroku).

So now we're going to plan B, which is to walk up the commit chain and test deploy each step of the way against Heroku until we figure out at which point it becomes un-compileable. (Yea, it's the best I could come up with at this point.)

So I figured I'd just clone the project locally, checkout some old commits, and push to heroku. But then I discovered that if I push to heroku from anything but master, it doesn't build the app?? Instead it says: "Pushed to non-master branch, skipping build."

So now even my bad plan is a non-starter. I'm just looking for a break here. Any ideas on how to do what im trying to do?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It’s not that Heroku only builds if you push *from* master, rather Heroku will only build if you push *to* master. If you just do

```
git push heroku
```

then you are probably pushing your local branch to one with the same name on Heroku (the exact default behaviour is configurable). You can push from a different local branch to Heroku master with

```
git push heroku my_local_branch:master
```

or, if you are already checked out on `my_local_branch` you could use

```
git push heroku HEAD:master
```

See the [documentation for `git push`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) – the examples towards the end in particular may help.

You will probably also need to use `-f` to force the push:

```
git push -f heroku my_local_branch:master
```

Comment: Awesome @matt- just what I needed. And I just found this described [in the heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments#advanced-linking-local-branches-to-remote-apps) as well. Question: why would I need to `-f` force though?

Comment: @Yarin If you’re trying to push an earlier commit than what is already on `master`, git will normally stop you. You need to use `-f` to say “yes I really mean to overwrite (and possibly lose) those later commits”.

Answer (score 20):

It's a lot easier to achieve the desired result with heroku instead of the multi-step git process of checking in code, and pushing it. This keeps your git history clean.

```
$ heroku releases
$ heroku rollback v11
```

Comment: Please add explanation as to why it's a better solution

Comment: I think the question was, how to deploy a commit that  has never been pushed to heroku remote before. You are giving solution on how to rollback to a commit that HAS been deployed to Heroku already

Answer (score 6):

If you want to push a certain commit to heroku, it's done like so:

```
git push heroku 5ad0f3d913f2a92cc095af9c7b6242263da58160:master
```

Simply replace `5ad0f3d913f2a92cc095af9c7b6242263da58160` with your desired commit.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3230241/5783745